# Making UISearch bar Transparent in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I ma trying to make search bar transparent in swift 4.

Here is my code

```
    let  searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "search
    searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
    searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

It ia appears like this 
[image]

I want to implement search bar as in screenshot.
Please can anyone suggest me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBarView:UISearchBar!

    searchBarView.placeholder = textStr
    searchBarView.setTextColor(color: .white)
    searchBarView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    searchBarView.layer.borderColor = searchBarView.barTintColor?.cgColor //orange
    searchBarView.setTextFieldColor(color: .clear)
    searchBarView.setPlaceholderTextColor(color: .white)
    searchBarView.setSearchImageColor(color: .white)
    searchBarView.setTextFieldClearButtonColor(color: .white)


  //MARK: - UISearchBar EXTENSION
    extension UISearchBar {

        private func getViewElement<T>(type: T.Type) -> T? {

            let svs = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
            guard let element = (svs.filter { $0 is T }).first as? T else { return nil }
            return element
        }

        func getSearchBarTextField() -> UITextField? {
            return getViewElement(type: UITextField.self)
        }

        func setTextColor(color: UIColor) {

            if let textField = getSearchBarTextField() {
                textField.textColor = color
            }
        }

        func setTextFieldColor(color: UIColor) {

            if let textField = getViewElement(type: UITextField.self) {
                switch searchBarStyle {
                case .minimal:
                    textField.layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
                    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 6
                case .prominent, .default:
                    textField.backgroundColor = color
                }
            }
        }

        func setPlaceholderTextColor(color: UIColor) {

            if let textField = getSearchBarTextField() {
                textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color])
            }
        }

        func setTextFieldClearButtonColor(color: UIColor) {

            if let textField = getSearchBarTextField() {

                let button = textField.value(forKey: "clearButton") as! UIButton
                if let image = button.imageView?.image {
                    button.setImage(image.transform(withNewColor: color), for: .normal)
                }
            }
        }

        func setSearchImageColor(color: UIColor) {

            if let imageView = getSearchBarTextField()?.leftView as? UIImageView {
                imageView.image = imageView.image?.transform(withNewColor: color)
            }
        }
    }



extension UIImage {

    func transform(withNewColor color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.setBlendMode(.normal)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        context.clip(to: rect, mask: cgImage!)

        color.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,It is working but image.transform line giving me error saying that" Value of type 'UIImage' has no member 'transform", If I comment this line button.setImage(image.transform(withNewColor: color), for: .normal) ,search icon is grayed out.

Comment: hii @PavithraPavi , i updated my answer check now... image extension i added. Now it will work,

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
```

or:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = .clear
```

Answer (score 4):

completely transparent all part of uisearchbar :

```
searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
```

- searchBar is an outlet of UISearchBar from storyBoard